# Deploying zuul proxy on kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, netflix-zuul, kubectl, kubelet

I have a Kubernetes cluster configured on Linux. On this, I want to configure zuul proxy. For deploying zuul, I am using zuul docker images from docker hub. But after running these zuul images, the pod status shows as 'ImagePullBackOff'. I used 2-3 repositories but all are showing the same status. I am either using 'kubectl create' or 'kubectl run' to install & configure zuul proxy. Can anybody let me know how can we install & configure zuul proxy on kubernetes cluster either by using docker images or any other method ?

Comment: Check the logs using `kubectl logs pod-name` for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to get [netflixoss/zuul](https://hub.docker.com/r/netflixoss/zuul/) image, ie `netflixoss/zuul:latest` but get the following error:

```
  Warning  Failed                 15s               kubelet, minikube  Failed to pull image "netflixoss/zuul": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: manifest for netflixoss/zuul:latest not found
  Warning  Failed                 15s               kubelet, minikube  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff                14s               kubelet, minikube  Back-off pulling image "netflixoss/zuul"
  Warning  Failed                 14s               kubelet, minikube  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling                0s (x2 over 18s)  kubelet, minikube  pulling image "netflixoss/zuul"
```

That's because there is only one version [1.0.28](https://hub.docker.com/r/netflixoss/zuul/tags/) available for image `netflixoss/zuul`. There is no default `latest` version for the image.

So, you need to deploy `netflixoss/zuul:1.0.28` image on your kubernetes cluster:

```
kubectl run --image netflixoss/zuul:1.0.28 zuul
```

It is successfully pulled:

```
  Normal  Pulling                21m   kubelet, minikube  pulling image "netflixoss/zuul:1.0.28"
  Normal  Pulled                 10m   kubelet, minikube  Successfully pulled image "netflixoss/zuul:1.0.28"
  Normal  Created                10m   kubelet, minikube  Created container
  Normal  Started                10m   kubelet, minikube  Started container
```

Comment: Thanks ..... your command worked. After running the image, I am trying to expose its service so that it can be accessible via a 'LoadBalancer' service. But it is not allocating an external IP. This is my local vm. Does 'LoadBalancer' service allocates IP on cloud instances only ?

Comment: Yes, `LoadBalancer` service type works only on cloud instances. You can use `NodePort` service type on your local VM to reach a `zuul` pod outside.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ..... since we are directly deploying zuul docker image on kubernetes cluster and exposing its service using NodePort, then how can we register zuul proxy with Eureka ? From what I have seen, we enter all the info in the application.properties file of zuul to register it with Eureka, but how to do it here ?